# What does the "blessed armor" affix?

Tags: the-mighty-quest-for-epic-loot

Just found a robe with this affix.  I like the way it sounds, but what's the effect exactly ?

[image: Blessed armor affix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer's lying in one of their [patch notes](https://www.themightyquest.com/en/forums/items-and-resources-feedback/topics/525armor#post-72189):

> We’ve added depth and diversity to the hero items by introducing new item abilities. In the past, you may have found items with basic abilities such as a chance to Stun or Poison your target. Pack 18 introduces the following new abilities:
>   [...]
>   • Blessed Armor :
>   The hero’s physical and magical armor is increased for a short duration
>   [...]
>   Your items have a chance to trigger one of its abilities any time you attack a creature.

Comment: "for short duration" makes me think this is some kind of activated ability.  So how do you activate it?

Comment: Check the last line of the patch note: `Your items have a chance to trigger one of its abilities any time you attack a creature.`  But I still don't know how long it lasts, neither what the chances to trigger it are...